# Setting/overriding an app deployment folder

Tags: xamarin.android

Is there a way to set or override a project deployment folder in Mono for Android?  For example, my application right now deploys to `/data/data/SolutionEngine/files/.__override__`

The nature of the application is that it loads plug-ins using Reflection, and by default it looks in the `/Adapters` sub-folder from the app root. This is how it works on the desktop and the Compact Framework, so for simplicity we'd like to continue to do the same on Android.

If I have a single solution that has the app and some plug-ins in it, I'd like those files to get deployed in the proper structure when I start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You could write out the plugins as android assets (see screenshot below). ***Please Note:*** You might need to change the extension to .mp3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566821/cant-get-file-descriptor-for-asset). I didn't have this issue though.

[image]

Once you do that, you should be able to get the assets by using the Asset Manager. You can copy them to a different folder or do whatever with them. Here is a sample of reading them into memory and them writing out the name.

```csh
const String pluginPath = "Plugins";

var pluginAssets = Assets.List(pluginPath);
foreach (var pluginAsset in pluginAssets)
{
    var file = Assets.Open(pluginPath + Java.IO.File.Separator + pluginAsset);

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.CopyTo(memStream);

        //do something fun.
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(memStream.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Loaded: {0}", assembly.FullName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to be able to debug the plug-ins as well, which doesn't seem to work.  Right now I'm using a hack where the code checks to see if the debugger is attached and if we're running on Android and makes a folder decision based on that.  It's ugly, but works until I find a better solution.