# Dynamically load dll from android_assets folder

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, .net-assembly

is it possible to load an dll with `Assembly.Load` when it's in the asset folder?

I have platform specific dll's for windows and android. I tried to use the android specific dll as asset (also in the build action), but when I try to load it into my app it's not found (I used the `path: file:///android_asset/mydll.dll`), and this only happens, if i build the app as release, in debug i get the necessary paths to load the library, but not from the assets folder.

What can I do? Is there another place, where I can put my dll to be loaded from my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of writing out assemblies to a Plugins folder and then reading them in and loading at runtime.

Make sure that you have your assemblies that you want to have go to the Assets folder set to a **Build Action of AndroidAsset**. See screenshot below.

*Please Note: You might need to change the extension to .mp3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566821/cant-get-file-descriptor-for-asset). I didn't have this issue though.*

[image]

Once you do that, you should be able to get the assets by using the Asset Manager. You can load them up or do whatever with them. Here is a sample of reading them into memory and the writing out the name.

```csh
const String pluginPath = "Plugins";

var pluginAssets = Assets.List(pluginPath);
foreach (var pluginAsset in pluginAssets)
{
    var file = Assets.Open(pluginPath + Java.IO.File.Separator + pluginAsset);

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.CopyTo(memStream);

        //do something fun.
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(memStream.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Loaded: {0}", assembly.FullName));
    }

}
```

In release mode, please be mindful that the Mono for Android is going to perform a static analysis of your libraries to perform a size optimization. If you are loading assemblies after this, then you may not have features that should have been included. The screenshot below shows the standard linking configuration for a release build. There are some flags and configurations that you can add to your code to help prevent linking ([Xamarin Docs on Linking](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Linking)), but I am not sure that there will be too much that you can do for dynamically loaded libraries.

[image: Mono for Android - Release Linking]

Comment: Thx, it works now to load the assembly, in a debug build I can use `platformAssembly.CreateInstance`, but in a release build I only get the Error: `The classes in the module cannot be loaded`. Did you also experience this problem?

Comment: Netbus, I updated my answer above. I believe the issue you are having is due to linking that is being done by the release build. Try turning linking off in the Properties > Mono Android Options screen and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question - I've no idea about loading assemblies from assets.

However, I do have quite a lot of experience of loading plugins in mvvmcross.

---

In mvx, we load platform specific plugins on droid by simply adding the dll as a refernce to the ui project and then calling `Assembly.Load` at runtime. This seems to work well.

Further, the same approach can be used in full windows applications - eg Wpf.

However, the same approach cannot be used on MonoTouch, Wp or WinRt - JIT and security/sandbox restrictions mean that you have to use some ui platform code to actually inject a code reference instead of using assembly.load. For more info, see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/build-new-plugin-for-mvvmcrosss.html?m=1