# Dynamicly resolving Assemblies without the file name

Tags: xamarin.android

Yes, I've read the warning label, and I know that dynamically loading assemblies is somewhat discouraged.  That said, I have an application that loads assemblies - that's just how it works.  It works fine on Windows.  Works fine on Windows CE.  I need it to "work fine" on Android, even if it takes some massaging.

Basically the app is an engine that loads up plug-in DLLs (we'll call it an Adapter) that meet specific interfaces at run time.  Under Windows, it even detects the appearance of a DLL at any point and goes and loads it - I'm fine if that's not going to work under Android.

What I'm having trouble getting working is having the Engine load an Adapter that it knew about at design/compile time but *without* hard coding the name of that Adapter into the Engine code.  I'm fine with adding a reference to the Adapter to get it to not get linked out, but I really, really don't want to have to add in the DLL name every time, as the DLLs change with different deployments, and that would lead to a huge headache.

So I figured that if it's referenced, it would get into the APK, and I could use reflection to load it like this:

```
var asm = Assembly.Load("TheAdapterName.dll");
```

Initial tests show that this works for the Adapter if I just hard code in the name, but again, I really, really want to avoid that.

So I thought that maybe I could reflect through the references and extract the name, but oddly, not all references actually show up when I do that.  So I do this:

```
var refs = asm.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(a => a.Name).ToArray();
```

And I get back an array of 14 assembly names.  But the assembly (asm) has **16** references, one of which is the Adapter plug-in I need to load.  The Adapter is definitely there - heck I used `Assembly.Load` with the full name two lines above and it resolved.

I thought, ok, maybe I can figure out the "path" to the folder from which I'm running, and then look for DLLs there and load that way.  Ha.  After several hours of trying to figure out a way to get the path that would work under Debug and Release, I came up with nothing but more grey hair.

Sooooo......  any thoughts on how I might get the name of a DLL that I know is in my APK, but that I don't "know" the name of at build time (I'm loading them and looking for interfaces via reflection to detect their "Adapterness").

Comment: There was a post a while back that covered a similar topic that I responded to. I am not sure if it would be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501562/dynamically-load-dll-from-android-assets-folder/14503045#14503045

Comment: Yes, I saw it.  The challenge is that now I have to compile the plug in to a DLL (right now it's just a project reference) and then add it into the project, which means I have to move to a two-step build, plus a third project for cases where I want to debug the plug-in.  I'm really trying to avoid adding that much work and brittleness to the release process because, again, these plug-in are different for each deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If those methods aren't working for you, then the only suggestion I can think of is to add a prebuild step which updates either a C# or an Assets file in order to provide the list you need.

Obviously this is extra work, but should be fully automated and is guaranteed to work no matter what platform changes get thrown at you.

---

As an aside, I also just looked at one of my mvx projects using reflector - it shows the same `asm.GetReferencedAssemblies()` list as your investigations report - runtime-loaded plugins are not listed. I guess that the `GetReferencedAssemblies` method is reporting only on assemblies actually used to import Type references at the IL level - so if you reference an assembly in the csproj but don't import any types then it doesn't list them as references in the compiled code.